# How do I specify a random effect in Bayesian beta regression model?

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, random-effects-model, beta-regression, bugs

My response data are proportions that I want to model with one continuous predictor and a random effect of group.

Here's my winbugs code:

```
##priors
    for (i in 1:n_group){
    alpha.group[i]~dnorm (mu.group.int, tau.group.int)   ### random intercepts
    }  

    mu.group.int ~ dnorm (0,0.001)  ### mean hyperparameter for group
    tau.group.int <- 1/(sigma.group.int * sigma.group.int)
    sigma.group.int ~ dunif(0,10) 

    phi ~ dgamma(0.1,0.1)
    a ~ dnorm(0,.001)
    b ~ dnorm(0,.001)

## model
for(i in 1:n) {
  y[i] ~ dbeta(alpha[i], beta[i])
  alpha[i] <- mu[i] * phi 
  beta[i]  <- (1-mu[i]) * phi
  logit(mu[i]) <- a + b*variable[i]+ alpha.group[group[i]] 
}
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
>     3 nodes produced errors; first error: Error in node y[1]
>   Invalid parent values

That makes me think the random effect is pushing the parent alpha and beta outside of the 0,1 limit....and maybe random effects/mixed levels are specified differently in these sort of models. Any help?